# No changes to commit Android studio SVN

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

I have an Android project on Android studio and I am trying to put it in my subversion repo and do commits. First I enabled version control in the VCS drop down menu in Android studio and imported my project into my subversion repository. The project is there and I can see it. When I make some changes to my code and try to commit it, it says "No changes detected". All my files are turned red too. Am I not doing something correctly? How do I do this?

Comment: Sorry for the stupd question, but hAve you added the files to your repo?

Answer (score 4):

By default, Android Studio doesn't mark local actions as repo actions.

To mark a newly created file as an SVN add, you can right-click on the file (either in the hierarchy or the editor tab) -> Subversion -> Add. As you can imagine though, this is quite cumbersome to do for every single file.

To change the setting so that newly created files are instantly marked as a repo add, go to Preferences -> Version Control -> Confirmation -> Add silently (under the 'When files are created' category).

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely doing something wrong here. If you can't determine what step is wrong or missing, then read the documentation.

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA so [it's documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/intellij-idea.html) should help. Take a closer look at this chapter: [Importing a Local Directory to Subversion Repository](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/importing-a-local-directory-to-subversion-repository.html).

Otherwise, try using a command-line client to [`svn import`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html) your Android Studio project to Subversion repository and then [`svn checkout`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) the working copy of this project to your machine. If you are curious what's going on with the working copy that gives you "No changes detected", run [`svn status -v`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) against it.

Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/)!

Answer (score 0):

First install [Tortoisesvn](https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html). During installation follow this steps

1.Run the the TortoiseSVN Installer.

2.Select the option to Modify.

3.select the **check box** "Install Command line client tools on to the local harddrive".

4.Add C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin to your Path environment variable or press CTRL+ALT+S in android studio. Then go to "Version Control"-> Subversion -> General -> Check the Checkbox "use commmand line client" and set the path to **C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe**

5.Restart IntelliJ.

```
This could be pretty easy rather than other stuff mentioned above. In 
Android studio1.5 version when you try to add the file in your project,
android studio will ask for a pop like "schedule for Addition"
to subversion?. select the check box (Remember, don't ask again) and click "yes". 
After this whatever the file you add or remove to your project it will automatically
synced to your svn repository. suppose if you didn't get that dialog, but you want to
add the newly added .png or xml file to svn means you can manually select those files 
which you have added (the newly added file will be in red color) right click 
on that file -> subversion -> Add to VCS or simply select the file and use (CTRL+ALT+A).
```

In the image green color(logo_actionbar) represents to file was already added to svn, red represents yet to add in svn. cool..!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### No changes to commit Android studio SVN

When your all project turns to red means your project is not version controlled. This means you have to add your project to SVN or checkout it from version control url.

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am describing the steps how to do it right way, take a look  - --

**Step :1)** Click on **VCS (in upper toolbar)** in dropdown click on **Checkout from Version Control** in its options Click on **Subversion**

You will see the popup like this -

[[image: Checkout popup [1]]

Step :2) Click on the '+' button(As Marked Red in Above Image) at the top and You will see the screen like this -

[image: Second Screen]

in the Edit area as shown above put the URL of your repository and click ok. And you will see the screen as below

[image]

Step :3) So as in the above image your URL will be shown in the text area with all its contents. Now click on Checkout (at bottom left). Next screen will be as below

[image]

Step :4) As seen in the above screen shot it will ask you for the Destination folder to checkout your code. Select the destination folder and click ok. And it will show you the screen as below.So after while your source code will be in the destination folder.

Step :5). After successful checkout it will ask to open the that code with Android Studio, click 'YES'.

[image]

Step :6) Now Goto Settings - > Version Control -> Subversion. As shown Below --

[image]

Step :7) As in the above screen there are three checkboxes (Marked as Blue Circles). So may be they are checked, now **Uncheck all the checkboxes and click ok.**

Step :8) Now close your Android Studio and restart Again.

Hope this will be Helpful !!

Happy Coding !!!! ;)

Comment: Step 7 alone saved the day. Thanks Easiest and best answer.